# Formatting existing SQL Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table full of a contacts information, and I want to change the phone number from 5555555555 to (555) 555-5555, instead.

I've found a few things online for selecting data and having it be returned in that format, but no way to actually update the records to use the new format. Is this even possible?

Comment: Just as a one-time update to all records?  A subset of records (maybe you've begun inserting new ones in the desired format already)?  Are you looking to change how the records are inserted as well?  It's not clear what your data cleanup strategy is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update YourTable
set PhoneNumber =
    '(' + LEFT(PhoneNumber, 3) +
    ') ' + SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber, 3, 3) +
    '-' + RIGHT(PhoneNumber, 4)
```

This will update your data with the correct format as you specified.  This works with **SQL Server**, but I can't speak for any other RDBMS.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I was trying to use CONCAT per recomendation of another resource, but SSMS didn't like it. This works perfefctly.

Answer (score 4):

it's a bad practice doing so in db. Good practice is to store raw data in your db and to format it when you're selecting it or even better - when you show this data to user.

Comment: The raw data, sure, I agree.  It should be just that...raw.  But I think a persisted computed column in the same table is a good idea.  It'll save the application retrieval time to format the phone number.

Comment: I can see your point, it's just that we're transferring from an Access DB to some SQL Platform my employer has purchased, and my boss wants the phone numbers and email addresses to be formatted accordingly for the transfer.

Thanks for the information, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer the old data format to the new one just make loop that read the cell change it to the format that you like and store it back in the cell.

```
string NewString;
NewString = "(" + TheOriginalString.Substring(0,3) + ") ";
NewString += TheOriginalString.Substring(3,3) + "-";   
NewString += TheOriginalString.Substring(6);
```

Then just store the new string in the same cell.
The example code is in C#.